# Cannot make CUDA example programs

Tags: cuda, makefile

I'm trying to make the 2 CUDA (4.2.9) example programs bandwidthTest and deviceQuery on a server running RHEL6.3, but got the error "-lshrutil not found". I googled a bit and read that the Shrutil libraries should not be needed anymore in CUDA 4.2 examples. But I still got the error.

How can I overcome this problem? Do I need to install any library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not all examples need shrutil anymore, some do, so yes you'll want to install the shrutil library

Comment: I see a "libshrutil_x86_64.a" in the /root/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/shared/lib directory. Is this the library I want? How do I use it?

Comment: You might try adding that path to your `LIBRARY_PATH` on your build line.. so something like `LIBRARY_PATH=/root/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/shared/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH make` .. if that doesn't work, this guy: http://stacksmashing.net/ (at the bottom) has build instructions running under centos 5.5 and cuda 3.2, they might still be applicable. In there he talks about building `shared/libshrutil.so` and whatnot, so might be able to gleam something useful out of that.

Answer (score 2):

The [release notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/doc/CUDA_SDK_Release_Notes.txt) related to Version 4.1 state (emphasis mine):

> **Several** of the CUDA C SDK samples have been restructed so they are self contained and no longer depend and no longer  link with CUTIL or SHRUTIL libraries

This does not imply that all samples no longer depend on them. So if you want to build all samples, you will still need both libraries.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by other answers, still you need to have this library. In RedHat/CentOS 64-bit like systems, the library is compiled with different name than `libshrutil.a` and there you cannot link to it by `-lshrutil` flag. To fix it, make a softlink with the proper name:

```
ln -s /root/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/shared/lib/libshrutil_x86_64.a /root/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/shared/lib/libshrutil.a
```

Then start top-level make of SDK and everything gonna work. That's it!